# .htaccess rewrite regex regular expressions

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My url is:

```
http://www.domain.com/Seattle_WA_math
```

It needs to point to:

```
http://www.domain.com/list.php?city=Seattle&state=WA&s=math
```

Here's what I have so far, doesn't work...

```
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z_\-]+_[A-Z]{2}_[A-Za-z0-9_\-\(\)]+\/$ list.php?city=$1&state=$2&$s=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z\-]+(?:_[A-Za-z\-]+)*)_([A-Z]{2})_([A-Za-z0-9_\-\(\)]+)\/?$ list.php?city=$1&state=$2&$s=$3 [L]
```

Allows multiple worded citys and subjects and optional trailing `/` path.

Answer (score 0):

I am typing this on the fly but it should work.

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)*([A-Z]{2})*([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ list.php?city=$1&state=$2&s=$3

The ( ) designate the $# variables in the end part so everything that matches should line up.

Comment: it didn't work... got a 404 not found error. I changed the script to RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)_([A-Z]{2})_([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/$ list.php?city=$1&state=$2&s=$3 [L] and it loaded but the none of the variables were grabbed

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+(?:_[A-Za-z-]+)*)_([A-Z]{2})_([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ /list.php?city=$1&state=$2&s=$3 [R,L,QSA,NE]
```

`R=301` will redirect with https status 301
`L` will make last rule
`NE` is for no escaping query string
`QSA` will append your existing query parameters

`$1`, `$2` and `$3` are groups in your REQUEST_URI

Comment: one small problem... some cities and subjects will have 2 or 3 words. http://www.domain.com/New_York_NY_algebra_1

Comment: @Jeffrey: I edited my answer above to take care of multiple `_` in city names and subject strings.